# Save HTTP POST Data from Form to use it more than once with Java, possible?

Tags: java, forms, servlets, http-post, struts

Maybe I haven't been asking the question in the correct way, but here is another attempt, and I'm gonna be more thorough this time. I made a super simple project to exemplify what I want to achieve.

I'm using netbeans and struts 1.3.

I have this very simple form:

```
 <html:form action="/firstUse.do" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <html:hidden property="anyname" value="whatevername" />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </html:form>
```

I have my ActionForm:

```
public class MyActionForm extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

private org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile file;
private String anyname;

public FormFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(FormFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public String getAnyname() {
    return anyname;
}

public void setAnyname(String anyname) {
    this.anyname = anyname;
}

public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

    int tamArchivo = file.getFileSize();
    String nomArchivo = file.getFileName();

    String extArchivo = nomArchivo.substring(nomArchivo.indexOf(".") + 1).toUpperCase();

    if (tamArchivo <= 0) {
        errors.add("", new ActionMessage("documentosEntregados.imagenVacia"));
    } else if (tamArchivo >= 1048576) { // 1 Mega
        errors.add("", new ActionMessage("documentosEntregados.imagenGrande"));
    }
    return errors;
}
}
```

I have my action:

```
public class FirstUse extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    MyActionForm myf = (MyActionForm) form;
    String name;
    String filename;

    name = myf.getAnyname();
    FormFile file = myf.getFile();
    filename = file.getFileName();

    System.out.println("FirstUse Action");
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(filename);
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
}
}
```

I have my filter:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    Throwable problem = null;
    try {

        String strPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath();

        if (strPath.endsWith("firstUse.do")) {

            System.out.println("Entered filter first");

            HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletRequestWrapper reqWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpReq);

            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

            // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
            ServletContext servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext();
            File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
            factory.setRepository(repository);

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(reqWrapper);

            Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
            if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("iter super empty");
            } else {
                System.out.println("iter not super empty");
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = iter.next();
                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                        System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName() + " Field value: " + item.getString());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("File found");
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Finished FirstUse, Now I want to do a second use");

            chain.doFilter(reqWrapper, response);
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("reqWrapper emtpy or not accessible");
        problem = t;
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (problem != null) {
        if (problem instanceof ServletException) {
            throw (ServletException) problem;
        }
        if (problem instanceof IOException) {
            throw (IOException) problem;
        }
    }
}
```

When I press submit, the filter is called, I wrap my request here:

```
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletRequestWrapper reqWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpReq);
```

**And Now, focus on the next, here is my problem. I'm gonna explain the behavior and what I want to achieve.**

IF I call first the next line:

```
chain.doFilter(reqWrapper, response);
```

The action executes properly and I get on system log my data:

```
FirstUse Action
whatevername
Elastix.jpg
Finished FirstUse, Now I want to do a second use
iter super empty
```

BUT when I get to try to iterate the request with apache commons, here:

```
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(reqWrapper);

            Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
            if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("iter super empty");
            }
```

POST Data is not accessible, so I get an empty iterator, stream is closed, that's the apache common fileupload exception thrown.

Now, If I first execute the iteration, instead of calling chain.doFilter, the iteration is done, and I get my results:

```
iter not super empty 
Field name: anyname 
Field value: whatevername 
File found
```

BUT when it gets to the chain.doFilter, again, POST Data is not accessible, so when I try to execute the action, I get null pointer exception, it even crashes before on validate if validation form is turned on, as the form values are null, the post data is gone.

So, after reading for many days and many hours, I've come to understand that I'm saving my HttpServletRequest effectively in my wrapper, BUT, when I try to use it again, of course the client doesn't send the iformation again, as it already gave it once, so the question here is:

**How could I emulate this behavior? How can I store the POST DATA to use it TWICE like I'm trying to do in my filter.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody comes across this problem, or try to implement this for some reason, well, I couldn't do it, but I found a work around. **Having in mind that my main restriction was not to modify the upload servlet(FirstUse.Action in this example)** , which I failed to mention in this question, I did the following to retrieve the data from the form after my action was already executed.

First I changed my form variables and methods to be static:

```
public class MyActionForm extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

private static org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile file;
private static String anyname;

public static FormFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(FormFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public static String getAnyname() {
    return anyname;
}

public void setAnyname(String anyname) {
    this.anyname = anyname;
}
```

Then, this way I could acces them from my filter simply calling the form methods:

```
    String name = MyActionForm.getAnyname();                
    FormFile imagen = MyActionForm.getFile();
```

And that was it, I no more needed to request POST data again from client, I take it right from the form. Very simple solution but took me many days to understand that you can't expect the client to send you the data twice, and figure out a work around to still get the data twice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this: 
chain.doFilter(request, response);

instead of this: 
chain.doFilter(reqWrapper, response);

Comment: Yeah, have tried both, they both work if invoked first, but if invoked the second time, they dont work, the request is there, but client has already responded, it won't respond 2 times, I need to emulate this behavior.